# How to visually simulate lightning and thunder?

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know of a clean way to simulate lightning and thunder mainly in jQuery/HTML5 without using video.. solely code and images. It's for sort of an image transition.

If not i may simply have to trick the eye with some fast flicker effects and sound. which i have no problem doing. Just wondered if anyone knows of a good tutorial or example.

thank in advance!
Jerry

Comment: Rather then using fast flicker effects just flicker in some imagery of lightning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the lightning, I would use a picture of lightning, and then jquery animation with a bounce ease out. That should give a fairly nice flicker effect with minimum effort.

As for thunder - sound is not guaranteed to work on all browsers, even if supported people often have sound turned off. And more importantly might be listening to their own music, or recording their own voice etc... so often don't appreciate websites interfering with their sound choices.

There are some sound libraries out there that cover most bases - I am sure someone else will answer that more fully for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plugin to generate various lightning effects:

http://js.binpress.com/product/jquery-lightning/3357

[example image of lightnings created with plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBEpN.png)